# Unable to establish connections between docker using docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Unable to establish connections between docker using docker-compose.yml

I am new to the docker world so apologies beforehand if my questions are not clear. So what I am trying to do is have two dockers one of which is rest service and the second one is the rest client. I am trying to establish the network connection between the two

**Path of the docker rest service /Users/gsha/learning/producer
Details about my rest service**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProducerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProducerApplication.class, args);
    }
}

package hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SimpleRest {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getHome(){
        return "Hello From Producer";
    }

}

server.port=8085
server.servlet.context-path=/producer-service

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","hello.Application"]
```

**Rest Client Info**

**Path  /Users/gsha/learning/consumer**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsumerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
   

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RestController
public class SimpleRestConsumer {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getHello(){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String val = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8085/producer-service", String.class);
        return val;
    }

}

server.port=8086
server.servlet.context-path=/consumer-service
address.service.base-path=http://localhost:8085/producer-service

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","hello.Application"]FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","hello.Application"]
```

**Path to the yaml file :/Users/gsha/learning/docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  producer-service:
    build:
      context: ../producer-service
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8085:8085

  consumer-service:
    build:
      context: ../consumer-service
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    depends_on:
      - producer-service
```

Getting this error when doing the deployment:

> docker-compose up --build
>
> [+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
> unable to prepare context: path "../producer-service" not found

Comment: The error is pretty clear - your compose file in `/Users/gsha/learning/` specifies that there is a Dockerfile at `../producer-service`, but that does not exist. Does `/Users/gsha/producer-service` exist, or did you mean something else?  Also, it is probably just formatting here on SO but the first 2 blocks of code you've added here look like a mix of code and Dockerfiles ... just to be sure, are those separate files?

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid service name. It looks like you accidentally added a `:` where it doesn't belong. You've written:

```
  consumer:-service:
    build:
    ...
```

But that should be:

```
  consumer-service:
    build:
    ...
```

---

Your new error is:

> unable to prepare context: path "../producer-service" not found

As @Don'tPanic's comment says, that seems pretty clear: you are asking `docker-compose` to find a directory named `producer-service` in the parent directory of the one that contains your `docker-compose.yml` file, and no such directory exists.

Comment: Thanks for bringing it up.I fixed that. Still getting the error in yaml file. Will you mind having a look again